# How to call a function X times a second reliably?

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to write a thread lib that supports setting a tps value. However, i have the problem, that when the tps is for example 15, the average time a tick lasts would be 66,667 ms. Since a thread can only sleep in full milliseconds, my solution to this would be to make a lookup table of which all values add up to 1000 ms.

So if i want to have 15 ticks per seconds i would just make a for loop from 0 to 14 and look up the maxmium sleep time in the table. My problem is how do i calculate the values in the lookup table?

My approach looks something like this:

```
int tps = 15;
int[] sleepTime = new int[tps];

float tickTime = 1000.0f / tps;
float increment = 1.0f - (tickTime - (int) tickTime);
float overflow = 0;
int c = 0;
for (int n = 0; n < tps; n++) {
    if (overflow >= 1) overflow = 0;
    sleepTime[n] = (int) tickTime + (int) Math.ceil(overflow);
    c += sleepTime[n];
    overflow += increment;
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sleepTime));
System.out.println("Complete sleep time: " + c);
```

This works fine for small values like 15, but when i want to have higher values like 31 tps, the sum of all calculated values is above 1000 (1007 for 31).

Comment: TBH, I would probably spinlock it for higher values. You won't get the precision you want with `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: Well, if want to have 20 tps, one tick should last 50ms. So if a method call needed 37ms i have to sleep 13ms, i think that's as precise as i can get with it. Of course the method call didn't take exactly 37ms, and the thread does not sleep exactly 13ms, but at least i can try to make it as accurate as possible, because otherwise if i want to have 120 tps (which is reasonable for a thread that handles openGL operations to achieve 120 frames) just using (int) 1000/120 will result in 125 fps

Comment: For values as low as 20, just use [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). For high values just spinlock - check if you should run in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subtract the value of the integer division from the remaining sleep time step by step:

```
int[] tps(int tps) {
    int[] sleepTimes = new int[tps];
    for (int i = 0, remainder = 1000; i < tps; i++) {
        int sleepTime = remainder / (tps - i);
        sleepTimes[i] = sleepTime;
        remainder -= sleepTime;
    }
    return sleepTimes;
}
```

Example evaluation of `tps(3)`:

- i = 0, remainder = 1000, sleepTime = 333
- i = 1, remainder = 667, sleepTime = 333
- i = 2, remainder = 334, sleepTime = 334
- i = 3 (remainder = 0, sleepTime = N/A)

To have an even distribution of floored and ceiled values, you could do the following:

```
int[] tps(int tps) {
    int[] sleepTimes = new int[tps];
    int low = 1000 / tps; // the floored value
    Arrays.fill(sleepTimes, low);
    int mod = 1000 % tps; // number of ceiled values to insert
    if (mod > 0) {
        int high = low + 1; // the ceiled value
        float rate = tps / (float) mod; // the insertion rate
        for (int i = 0; i < mod; i++) {
            sleepTimes[Math.round(i * rate)] = high;
        }
    }
    return sleepTimes;
}
```

`tps(21)`: [**48**, *47*, **48**, **48**, *47*, **48**, **48**, *47*, **48**, *47*, **48**, **48**, *47*, **48**, *47*, **48**, **48**, *47*, **48**, **48**, *47*]

Comment: well this works in the way that the sum of the values will always be 1000, but they  aren't evenly distributed in the array. For example if i use tps = 31, the array first has 23 32s and then 8 33s.

Comment: @Masy I have now addressed this with a second method.

Answer (score 0):

[`Thread.sleep(long millis, int nanos)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-int-) sleeps both milliseconds and nanoseconds. 
So calculate the exact sleep time and just fire a worker (in another thread) and re-sleep. That means that the workers execution time doesn't matter.

To avoid drifting errors make the sleep calculation based on a start time and a counter. Every know and then the thread will sleep a little less to compensate for the small amount of time it takes to handle the sleep timer it self.